# Bulk assign paths to nodes

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I have a bespoke content type with a lot of nodes, but alias urls have not been assigned to them. I need to bulk assign them consistent alias. I know on Drupal 7 this is possible to do using pathauto, however I have installed that for Drupal 8 and the batch assignment doesn't seem to be working yet. Is there another efficient way this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

1) Make sure you have set up a working alias for your content type at /admin/config/search/path/patterns

2) Go to /admin/config/search/path/update_bulk

3) check "Content"

4) Submit

I have just tested this on my local dev environment by going in the db and deleting the alias to one node:

```
delete from url_alias where source = '/node/2940'
```

and running the bulk operation generated an alias for all unaliased nodes (which just happened to be the only one I deleted).

So if the bulk operation isn't working for you, it may be that you don't have a pattern set up for your content type (node bundle).

Check at /admin/config/search/path/patterns and make sure you have a working pattern set up for your content type.

Comment: Yes, I did do exactly this but it didn't work. I'll try again. I assume you tested with the 8.2 and the latest version of pathauto?

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to make sure the flag **Generate automatic URL alias** is set before you perform the bulk update (/admin/config/search/path/update_bulk)

```
$entity->get('path')->__set('pathauto', TRUE);
```